# The specified condition is not a valid Transact-SQL expression

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm attempting to set a conditional breakpoint in Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

The condition is simple: `@RCICID IS NOT NULL`. I'm pretty certain this is a valid expression. I've also tried `@RCICID != ''`, which has the same result:

[image: breakpoint error]

How could I possibly make the condition more valid? Is there some other possible explanation for this error?

Comment: Try to use IsNull function. `IsNull(@RCICID, '') <> ''`

Comment: That didn't work either. Same result.

Comment: I can reproduce that, I get the same error on basicly any condition I try.

Comment: Code below is using regular breakpoints: `use master;

declare @RCICID nvarchar(255);

--set @RCICID = 'test';

if IsNull(@RCICID,'')=''
 select @RCICID;
else
 select @RCICID;

print @RCICID;`

Comment: `@RCICID IS NOT NULL` is a valid expression provided `@RCICID` is in scope. What's the actual code you're trying to set the breakpoint on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NULL value is invalid when evaluated in an SSMS 2012 breakpoint condition (so using `ISNULL()` doesn't help).

Declare a test variable and set the variable to a non-null value, then set the breakpoint on the value of the test variable.

```
...
DECLARE @Null_RCICID integer;

SET @Null_RCICID = CASE WHEN @RCICID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
...
```

The set the breakpoint condition `@Null_RCICID=1`